# When do I have to make entities serializable when using EJB3?

Tags: java, serialization, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I use all of my entities `Serializable`. However I think it is okay to use without serializable.

But what are the advantages of making an entity `Serializable`? When do we really have to serialize an entity / or when do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html) (which is quoting [JSR-317](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html) §2.1):

> #### Requirements for Entity Classes
>
> ...
> If an entity instance is passed by value as a detached object, such as through a session bean’s remote business interface, the class must implement the `Serializable` interface.
> ...

Comment: so it is necessary to implement serializable only if remote interface is being used, right?